# How do I plot a bar graph in ggplot where my bins are year-months

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
mydates<-data.frame(effectiveDate=as.Date(c("2012-1-1","2012-1-1","2012-2-1","2012-10-1","2012-4-1","2012-8-1","2013-1-1")))
```

How do I plot a bar graph using ggplot where the bars are year-months?  In this case, there'd be 13 bars: "Jan 2012" through "Jan 2013" and each bar height would represent the count of each date that falls in the month.

Comment: you could give us some data to play with so we can show you :)

Comment: I think the data's there already...?

Comment: Have you tried: `ggplot(data=mydates, aes(x=effectiveDate)) + geom_histogram(stat="bin", position="identity")`

Comment: @Arun this doesn't look quite right, just from eyeballing the graph.  I'll have to look into it more to know for sure.

Comment: Umm... as long as the counts are "0", you can not expect bars for those months. I don't see what's different from your requirement.

Comment: @Arun, you are right.  It worked, it just had some strange formatting that threw me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works:

**Edit: Per the comments below**

```
mydates$months <- month.abb[as.numeric(format(mydates[, 1], format = "%m"))]
mydates$Months <- paste(mydates$months, format(mydates[, 1], format = "%y"))
mydates$Months <- factor(mydates$Months, levels = paste(month.abb, c(rep(12, 12), 13)))

ggplot(mydates, aes(Months)) + geom_bar()+ scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=.3))
```

The labels could be adjusted by making the bars horizontal with `coord_flip()` or using `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=.3))`

[image]

Comment: Tyler, I think he needs 13 bars (with month + year on x-axis).

Comment: This orders the bars incorrectly, and you lose the distinction between years.

Comment: @Ben you made no specification about order of bars.  What is correct?  Stephen Few proposes ordering by Frequency so you must be specific.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

```
ggplot(data = mydates, aes(x = effectiveDate)) + geom_bar() 
ggsave(filename = "~/temp/temp.png", width = 6, height = 3, dpi = 150)
```

[image]