# How to make a bar graph in ggplot that groups months of different years

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe, `df`:

```
df
   EffYr EffMo count        dts
2   2012     1     1 2012-01-01
3   2012     2     3 2012-02-01
4   2012     3     1 2012-03-01
5   2012     5     1 2012-05-01
6   2012     6     1 2012-06-01
7   2012     7     2 2012-07-01
8   2012     8    11 2012-08-01
9   2012     9    84 2012-09-01
10  2012    10   184 2012-10-01
11  2012    11   165 2012-11-01
12  2012    12   246 2012-12-01
13  2013     1   414 2013-01-01
14  2013     2   130 2013-02-01
15  2013     3   182 2013-03-01
16  2013     4   261 2013-04-01
17  2013     5   229 2013-05-01
18  2013     6   249 2013-06-01
19  2013     7   330 2013-07-01
20  2013     8   135 2013-08-01
```

Each row of `df` represents a "month-year", the earliest being Jan 2012 and the latest being Aug 2013.  I want to plot a bar graph (using ggplot2) where each bar represents a row of `df` with the bar height equal to the row's `count`.  So, I should have 24 bars in total.

I want my x axis to be divided into 12 intervals: Jan-Dec, and bars that represent the same calendar month should lie in the same "month interval". For example, if `df` has a row for Jan 2011, Jan 2012, Jan 2013, then the Jan portion of my graph should have 3 bars so that I can compare my business's performance in the month of January for subsequent years.

Thanks

Edit: I want something that looks like

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, fill=cut)) + geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(. ~ clarity)
```

But broken down by month.  I tried to modify that code to fit my data, but never could get it right.

Comment: This sounds like an order from a take out restaurant.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @TylerRinker, haha.  See the edit in my post.

Comment: How is this problem different than: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557602/how-do-i-plot-a-bar-graph-in-ggplot-where-my-bins-are-year-months/17557895#17557895

Comment: Oh I see you want the months grouped together.  Could you make up a data set with at least 2 years of data so we don't have to?

Comment: @TylerRinker Sure. See df in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ben you're asking a number of ggplot2 questions.  I would recommend you sit down with some good ggplot2 resources and try the example to become more skilled.  Here are 2 excellent resources I use often:

http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/

Now the solution I think you're after:

```
## dat <- read.table(text="   EffYr EffMo count        dts
## 2   2012     1     1 2012-01-01
## 3   2012     2     3 2012-02-01
## 4   2012     3     1 2012-03-01
## 5   2012     5     1 2012-05-01
## 6   2012     6     1 2012-06-01
## 7   2012     7     2 2012-07-01
## 8   2012     8    11 2012-08-01
## 9   2012     9    84 2012-09-01
## 10  2012    10   184 2012-10-01
## 11  2012    11   165 2012-11-01
## 12  2012    12   246 2012-12-01
## 13  2013     1   414 2013-01-01
## 14  2013     2   130 2013-02-01
## 15  2013     3   182 2013-03-01
## 16  2013     4   261 2013-04-01
## 17  2013     5   229 2013-05-01
## 18  2013     6   249 2013-06-01
## 19  2013     7   330 2013-07-01
## 20  2013     8   135 2013-08-01", header=TRUE)

dat$month <- factor(month.name[dat$EffMo], levels = month.name)
dat$year <- as.factor(dat$EffYr)

ggplot(dat, aes(month, fill=year)) + geom_bar(aes(weight=count), position="dodge")
```

[image]